# In Cocoa get an error saving an image

Tags: cocoa, properties, png, nsdata

I was using this code for save a pic after I scaled it:

```
NSData *dataToWrite = [rep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType  properties:nil];

[dataToWrite writeToFile:finalPath atomically:NO];
```

and it was working fine, but now with new Xcode I get a warning:

> Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument

What should I put in properties instead of nil?

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem I resolved creating this NSDictionary:

```
NSDictionary * dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5] forKey:NSImageCompressionFactor];
```

and putting "dict" instead of nil in properties.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass an `NSDictionary`, with the possible keys to the dictionary being found in `NSBitmapImageRep.h` (You can pass in an empty dictionary, though)

```
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString* NSImageCompressionMethod;   // TIFF input/output (NSTIFFCompression in NSNumber)
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString* NSImageCompressionFactor;   // TIFF/JPEG input/output (float in NSNumber)
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString* NSImageDitherTransparency;  // GIF output (BOOL in NSNumber)
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString* NSImageRGBColorTable;       // GIF input/output (packed RGB in NSData)
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString* NSImageInterlaced;      // PNG output (BOOL in NSNumber)
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString* NSImageColorSyncProfileData;    // TIFF,GIF input/output (NSData)
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString* NSImageFrameCount;  // GIF input (int in NSNumber) (read-only)
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString* NSImageCurrentFrame;    // GIF input (int in NSNumber)
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString* NSImageCurrentFrameDuration;    // GIF input (float in NSNumber) (read-only)
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString* NSImageLoopCount            ;   // GIF input (int in NSNumber) (read-only)
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString* NSImageGamma                ;   // PNG input/output (float in NSNumber)
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString* NSImageProgressive          ;   // JPEG input/output (BOOL in NSNumber)
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString* NSImageEXIFData             ;   // JPEG input/output (NSDictionary)
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString* NSImageFallbackBackgroundColor  NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_5); // JPEG output (NSColor)
```

Comment: You have a lot of choices, see the class reference for how to create an NSDictionary: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-SW10

You can also just use the literal, `@{}` 

The strings in my answers are the possible properties you can modify (see class reference for more details).  You can use those NSStrings* as keys in the dictionary, with the values being the value you want the property to be

Comment: If you don't want any properties, just do this:
`NSData *dataToWrite = [rep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType  properties:@{}];`